# How can I input the equation below in Abaqus （Operate on XY Data） with certain condition? Where fi=5+5i and frequency range is between 300-950; S=189

Tags: finite-element-method, abaqus

Where fi=5+5i and frequency range is between 300-950; S=189.

[image: Where fi=5+5i and frequency range is between 300-950; S=189.]